# Angular Material Limit toggling of MatExapansionPanel to only clicking arrow

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-material

I'm using Angular Material to create my toggling panels. I still want my panel to expand and contract when clicking the arrow, but I not when I click anywhere in the panel header because I want to add a checkbox at the top. Currently, when I click on my checkbox, the toggling event of the panel fires when I click the checkbox. The 'change' event of the checkbox still fires afterward.

I don't mind to have the panel toggles only when clicking its arrow, how do I stop the toggling of the panel from firing when clicking anywhere in the top?

HTML

```
<mat-expansion-panel #panel
       (opened)="togglePanel()"
       (closed)="togglePanel()">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <mat-panel-title>
            <mat-checkbox (change)="onCheckChanged($event)">
                <label>Options 1</label>
            </mat-checkbox>
        </mat-panel-title>
        <mat-panel-description></mat-panel-description>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

TypeScript

```
togglePanel() {
    // this event fires before the onCheckChanged event
}

onCheckChanged(event: MatCheckboxChange) {
    // this event fires after the togglePanel event
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is currently a feature request in for this, about a year old so not sure of the ETA... seems to be some workarounds people are playing with that might help but appear to have mixed reviews.

https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/8190

---

**Revision**

I tested the following in stackblitz and it seems to work.

**HTML**

```
<mat-accordion>
  <mat-expansion-panel #expansionPanel>
    <mat-expansion-panel-header (click)="expandPanel(expansionPanel, $event)">
```

**Component**

```
 expandPanel(matExpansionPanel, event): void {
        event.stopPropagation(); // Preventing event bubbling

        if (!this._isExpansionIndicator(event.target)) {
          matExpansionPanel.close(); // Here's the magic
        }
      }



   private _isExpansionIndicator(target: EventTarget): boolean {
    const expansionIndicatorClass = 'mat-expansion-indicator';

    return (target['classList'] && target['classList'].contains(expansionIndicatorClass) );
  }
```

**Stackblitz**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5kugm3?embed=1&file=app/expansion-overview-example.html

Comment: the link throws error about classList not being available in EventTarget. It does the same in webstorm.

Comment: Please see revised link, the classList is there, just the IDE's complaining about the dot notation... converted to bracket notation. `target['classList']`

Comment: You should replace `.close();` with `.toggle()` so that clicking the title when expanded doesn't close it when open either